# Get objects having id in 1st array as same as id in objects of other array in java script

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 arrays of objects.
They are

```
array1 = [{
  id:2,
  name:"person2"
},{
  id:3,
  name:"person3"
},
{
  id:4,
  name:"person4"
},
{
  id:5,
  name:"person5"
},
];
array2 = [
{
    empId:2,
    isdeleted:false
},
{
    empId:4,
    isdeleted:false
}, 
{   
    empId:3,
    isdeleted:true
}];
```

I need the object from array1 whose id matches with empId of array2 and having isdeleted false. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have attempted it but I didn't get what i expected.Below is the query i have tried. Can u help me with this Roope.     this.array1.filter(o => this.array2.find(o2 => o.id === o2.empId))

Comment: Okay, you should include your efforts in the question. The first thing said behind the link is "It appears no attempt was made". Emphasis on "appears". If you do not give any indication of an attempt in your question, others can only assume that you have not attempted anything yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this:

```js
let array1 = [{
    id: 2,
    name: "person2"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "person3"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "person4"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "person5"
  },
];

let array2 = [{
    empId: 2,
    isdeleted: false
  },
  {
    empId: 4,
    isdeleted: false
  },
  {
    empId: 3,
    isdeleted: true
  }
];

let filteredArray = array1.filter(a => array2.some(b => b.empId === a.id && !b.isdeleted));
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: One more question is that if in array2 I have age as well. then if i want the resultant object as {id:some_id,name:some_name,age:some_age}. Is that possible?

Comment: You want to filter based on age as well?

Comment: I have edited the comment. Would you please look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let result = [];
array1.forEach(function(element1){
    array2.forEach(function(element2){
        if (element1.id === element2.empId && !element2.isdeleted){
            result.push(element);
        }
    });
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
let array1 = [
    { id:2, name:"person2"},
    { id:3, name:"person3"},
    { id:4, name:"person4"},
    { id:5, name:"person5"}
];
  
let array2 = [
    { empId:2, isdeleted:false},
    { empId:4, isdeleted:false}, 
    { empId:3, isdeleted:true}
];

let result = array1.reduce((output, item) => {
    if (array2.find((item2) => !item2.isdeleted && item.id === item2.empId)) output.push(item);
    return output;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter()` together with `find()` to find the object with that condition in `array2`:

```js
var array1 = [{
    id: 2,
    name: "person2"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "person3"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "person4"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "person5"
  },
];
var array2 = [{
    empId: 2,
    isdeleted: false
  },
  {
    empId: 4,
    isdeleted: false
  },
  {
    empId: 3,
    isdeleted: true
  }
];

var res = array1.filter((obj1)=>{
  var exist = array2.find((obj2)=> (obj1.id == obj2.empId && !obj2.isdeleted));
  return exist;
});
console.log(res);
```